# SpiffyUI: help configuring existing GWT project; in particular, how exactly is spiffyui.min.js being found?

Tags: gwt, ant

I feel as if I must be missing something obvious here.  The Getting
Started page here http://www.spiffyui.org/?getStarted
says, among other things:

> 1. Add the Spiffy project dependency You can have Spiffy automatically downloaded through a Nexus server, or you can manually download JARs
>      from our downloads page. . . . .

Ok, I just use Apache Ant the way it was configured by the GWT
project generator.  I downloaded the two .jar files and told the
build.xml file to copy them into war/WEB-INF/lib when I build.

(also setting spiffyui.sdk at the top)

```
   <!-- Add any additional server libs that need to be copied -->
   <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/lib" file="${spiffyui.sdk}/spiffyui-0.7.8.jar" />
   <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/lib" file="${spiffyui.sdk}/spiffytasks-0.7.8.jar" />
```

> 1. Reference Spiffy in your HTML Now the CSS and JavaScript files are included in your project when you build. The next step is to reference
>      them in your HTML file. The Spiffy UI framework includes many
>      JavaScript and CSS files, but they are all combined into two files for
>      faster application loading. Reference this one file and the JQuery
>      library in the head section of your HTML files like this:

```
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="spiffyui.min.js"></script>
   ...
   </head>
```

Ok, done.

> 1. Import Spiffy in your GWT module The last step is to import the Spiffy UI framework GWT module. Add the following line to your GWT
>      module file:

```
   <inherits name="org.spiffyui.spiffyui" />
```

Ok, done

> That's all it takes.

Really?

So now I am serving html file that refers to spiffyui.min.js as a
local file.  It seems to me that I should tell my web server to serve
that file.  I could not figure out where I was supposed to get that
file until I looked in the .jar files and found org/spiffyui/public/js/
spiffyui.js .  Hmm, well maybe these Java web containers automatically
look for files down in the .jar libraries and serve them??!  Sounds
odd, but ok.

I tried running under dev mode and then I manually went to the URL
that the script tag src property should imply:
http://127.0.0.1:8888/spiffyui.min.js
result: 404 Not found

maybe I need to special modified URL for dev mode?:
http://127.0.0.1:8888/spiffyui.min.js?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
result: nope, 404 Not found

What am I missing here?

Comment: If that is the case, then how can their code work?

Comment: A relative URL, such as the one they provide in the code I quoted above, namely src="spiffyui.min.js", is computed relative to the address from which the page containing it was obtained.  It doesn't matter if that's 127.0.0.1:8888 or your.com, that relative URL is going to map to the same place on the server.  Therefore their code shoudl work whether deployed or run locally, and yet it does not work when run locally.

Answer (score 1):

The magic you're missing is the GWT compiler. When you add the module dependency to your GWT project for Spiffy UI you're giving the framework a chance to be part of your projects complication.  Part of that means it will copy the spiffyui.min.js file out of the JAR files and into to the same directory in your project output as the rest of your GWT code.

Once the file is copied out the reference you added to your HTML file works because it can pick up spiffyui.min.js with a relative URL.  Once the JavaScript loads Spiffy UI can import CSS and anything else it needs to make the framework run.

I hope this helps,
Zack

Comment: Not really.  By running ant devmode, I *am* running the GWT compiler.  What you are really saying is that my ant build.xml is not configured to tell the GWT compiler to do something that results in that spiffyui.min.js file being copied out of the .jar file.  What I need to know is how to configure build.xml to do that.

Comment: Ok, so by running the ant build target, I then *do* get these .js files copied out of the .jar file and into the war.  So the question is how to make this happen in devmode.

Comment: Ah, you're Zack, the maintainer of Spiffy UI.  Well Spiffy looks rather spiffy, but what would be even more spiffy would be if you would give explicit instructions on how to add spiffy to an existing GWT build process the way it is generated by the Google GWT project creator wizard, rather than only providing me with a wizard that generates a whole new build process when I may not want that.  I followed the instructions on your page and while building may be working, I need devmode to also be working.

Comment: Ok, so I just found the Spiffy UI page on devmode: http://www.spiffyui.org/?hostedMode ; however it just says "Use Eclipse"; I do not want to use Eclipse, I want to use emacs and command-line tools; how do I do that?

Comment: Ok, even when I *do* run the gwtc compiler, the .js files are put into the wrong directory for my configuration; I should be able to run without devmode (using Google App Engine) and use the app, but instead I get these warnings for missing files when I load the page: WARNING: No file found for: /spiffyui.min.js ; I can see where the .js files are supposed to go, they just don't get put there by the module when it is compiled, they get put in a subdirectory of that; I could fix that, but now I'm really hacking; this is not a drop-in solution.

Comment: The short version of this thread is that Spiffy UI is set up for its own project management configuration and does *not* work as a drop-in modification for an existing vanilla GWT project as generated by the GWT project generator.  As far as I can tell, this means that to use it I'm going to have to (1) generate a Spiffy UI project, and then (2) port my entire project into that.  This is a big risk, as it makes it hard to turn Spiffy UI off again if I don't like it.  I think this is a mistake in the way you have Spiffy UI set up: it should be "humble" and allow easily for other build systems.

Comment: The Spiffy UI project creator is just a shortcut to help you get started.  Spiffy UI is just like any other GWT module where you need to manage your classpath and make sue evertyhing ends up in the right place.  The Spiffy UI sample projects include many examples of using custom builds for other environments like PHP, Gradle, and Node.js.  There's also no requirement to use Eclipse.  GWT has extra support for Eclipse, but it's possible to get all of this running on the command line.  You might want to reach out to iour mailing list if you have more specific questions.  Thanks, Zack

Comment: I tried the example HelloSpiffyAnt and it did not help as it exhibits its own organization of the project layout and build process, not one mirroring that of the default GWT project organization.  Again, I ask for what purpose have a project layout and build process that as far as I can tell is gratuitously different from the GWT default?  No mailing list being evident on your site's help page, I assume by your mailing list, you mean your Google Group?  I will basically post the same question there; not sure how it is that it couldn't have simply been answered here.

Comment: The Google Group is what I meant for our mailing list.  The project layout in the samples tries to find a blanace between project layouts which will be familiar to Ant users and Maven users.

Spiffy UI can work with any project layout you want.  If you're having trouble making it work with a specific project organization please let us know and we'll resolve the issue.

Thanks,
Zack

Comment: @ChrisCashwell everything I said is carefully articulated as a point in engineering language and addressing the concern at hand.  Reading emotion into text is a common problem.  Whatever you do, please stop attributing your emotions to me.

Comment: @ZackGrossbart I have tried to articulate my request clearly on your Google group.  I specified exactly the setup that I'm trying to make work.  I'll look for your response there.